# Rails / Mina Gem Creating Custom task to do seeding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, seed, mina

I'm using the mina gem since 2 weeks and I've searched online to find a nice way to do my seeding in my rails staging.

The seed must be a task so it is not called every time a deploy is done.

What I already have is the following:

```
desc "Seed data to the database"
task :seed do
    queue "bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=staging"
end
```

Do you think this is correct, I know for 100% that it works if I just type the command on the server.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first tried using verbose like

```
mina seed --verbose
```

This gave me the error:

```
Could not locate gemfile
```

So he could not reach the gemfile on the server so I had to do the following:

```
desc "Seed data to the database"
task :seed => :environment do
  queue "cd apps/default/current"
  queue "bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=staging"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`mina "rake[db:seed]" -v`

`-v` param is optional (verbose).